# Comparing two sorted dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, compare

I have two dictionaries like that:

```
            Dictionary<int, string> main = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> other = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        main.Add(0, "fruit;banana");
        main.Add(1, "fruit;apple");
        main.Add(2, "fruit;cherry");
        main.Add(3, "fruit;pear");

        other.Add(0, "fruit;blueberry");
        other.Add(1, "fruit;pear");
        other.Add(2, "fruit;orange");
```

I need sort this two dictionaries and at the output i want of a third dictionary, which has all the sorted fruit

Comment: What should the third dictionary have as its keys and values? They clearly can't be the same as in the two dictionaries you have since you have duplicate keys between them.

Comment: What should the third dictionary look like? For example, what do we do about duplicate keys (e.g. `main[0]` and `other[0]`)?

Comment: @Chris haha i think you beat me to it :)

Comment: `Dictionary` is not a collection type that specifies or cares about ordering of its values, so sorting a Dictionary does not make any sense (but you can sort the *values* into another collection or enumeration).

Comment: Or u can use SortedDictionary, if fruits will be keys hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are not clear with your question what you want the third dictionary to look like, I will guess that what you want is a dictionary where the values are all of the sorted fruits from the first two dictionaries, and the keys are simply counting up (as in the first two dictionaries).

You could make such a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> allFruits =
    main.Values.Concat(other.Values)
    .OrderBy(f => f)
    .Select((f, i) => new { fruit = f, index = i })
    .ToDictionary(o => o.index, o => o.fruit);
```

The result, based on your given `main` and `other` dictionaries:

```
[0, "fruit;apple"]
[1, "fruit;banana"]
[2, "fruit;blueberry"]
[3, "fruit;cherry"]
[4, "fruit;orange"]
[5, "fruit;pear"]
[6, "fruit;pear"]
```

If you don't want `fruit;pear` to show up twice, you can insert a `.Distinct()` call in there:

```
Dictionary<int, string> allFruits =
    main.Values.Concat(other.Values)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(f => f)
    .Select((f, i) => new { fruit = f, index = i })
    .ToDictionary(o => o.index, o => o.fruit);
```

Comment: thanks, yesterday i need to end my work that why i not finished my question